# How do I change the font size of previously written text in a textBrowser?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextbrowser

In my program, I am trying to automatically resize text size whenever the window size changes. I have used resizeEvent to do this and it is recognizing when the window is resized. However, whenever I try to change the font size using setFontPointSize it doesn't work. The only way I can get it to work is to use setText and use the HTML to change the font size, however, this is not desirable as I can't access widget size and variables inside the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you change the font with `setFontPointSize` you will do it for the new text, if you want it to apply to all the text you must select it and just change the font size:

```
class TextBrowser: public QTextBrowser{
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event){
        QTextBrowser::resizeEvent(event);
        //some criteria to obtain the new font size
        qreal size = 0.1*event->size().width();
        QTextCursor cursor = textCursor();
        selectAll();
        setFontPointSize(size);
        setTextCursor(cursor);
    }
};
```

A complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48837105)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I did Qt in the summer and completely forgot the syntax.

Comment: @AbhiGarg If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct. If you do not know how to do it, check the [tour]

Comment: I marked it as correct. Could you also tell me the function for unselecting after?